# How does JQGrid or jTable form the popup?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, jquery-jtable

i am interested to know how JQGrid or jTable show a popup when add New record link is clicked or when edit icon on a row is clicked?

Reason why am asking is, I want to see if i can create a grid of my own which will support CRUD operations.  Many of you might be thinking why am i reinventing the wheel, but let me tell you I don't want to if i find a free grid with CRUD features using bootstrap framework.

jtable uses jquery UI and jqgrid is not free, so i have no other option.

Even if i find a tool, it would be interesting to know how these grids generate the popup dynamically based on the colModel.

Comment: jqGrid has an optional commercial license but "jqGrid is and will always be licensed under the most permissive and free MIT license." (Taken from [their page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=932))

Comment: Only the server-side jqGrid components cost money. Everything else, including *all* of the JavaScript code, is freely licensed.

Comment: Hi Justin, how do i confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) component to create custom dialogs to perform add/edit operations using jqGrid. This allows a level of customization beyond that provided by the grid.

If you do not want to use jQuery UI, you can find a bootstrap-specific one such as [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/):

> Bootbox.js is a small JavaScript library which allows you to create programmatic dialog boxes using Twitter’s Bootstrap modals, without having to worry about creating, managing or removing any of the required DOM elements or JS event handlers.

---

That said, you could use the built-in add/edit form from jqGrid if the [license](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=154) is acceptable:

> The jqGrid is released under GPL and MIT licenses. This license policy makes the software available to everyone for free (as in free beer) and you can use it for commercial or open source projects, without any restriction (the freedom above).

But keep in mind that jqGrid is built on top of jQuery UI.